# Discord Bot doesn't send anything in channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create Welcome bot for discord.
And I ran into problem.
I must say that this bot development is new to me and I am just trying to create something for my friend's Discord server.

Now, bot starts and it's running, but it's supposed to send that "Welcome message" and other stuffs in channel I provided, but it doesn't do anything.

Here's the part of code I wrote and I think bug occurs there.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let channel = member.guild.channels.find("name","✦general");
    let memberavatar = member.user.avatarURL
    if (!channel) return;
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setThumbnail(memberavatar)
        .addField(':bust_in_silhouette: | Ime : ', `${member}`)
        .addField(':microphone2: | Zdravo!', `Dobro došao u dolinu , ${member}`)
        .addField(':id: | User :', "**[" + `${member.id}` + "]**")
        .addField("**[" + `${member.id}` + "]**",'Pročitaj naša pravila u',"**[#✦pravila]**")
        .addField(':family_mwgb: | Sada si član', `${member.guild.memberCount}`)
        .addField("Name", `<@` + `${member.id}` + `>`, true)
        .addField(':family_mwgb: | Luda zabava tek počinje')
        .addField('Server', `${member.guild.name}`, true )
        .setFooter(`**${member.guild.name}**`)
        .setTimestamp()

    channel.sendEmbed(embed);
});

let channel = member.guild.channels.find("name","✦general");
```

I think that this could be problem, but I am not entierely sure.

Debugger doesn't show anything except: Logovan si kao Crack House Welcome#6046!
Which I wrote to make sure bot is running, it means "You are logged as".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === '✦general');
let memberavatar = member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true });
if (!channel) return;
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setThumbnail(memberavatar)
    .addField(':bust_in_silhouette: | Ime : ', `${member.user}`)
    .addField(':microphone2: | Zdravo!', `Dobro došao u dolinu , ${member.user}`)
    .addField(':id: | User :', "**[" + `${member.id}` + "]**")
    .addField("**[" + `${member.id}` + "]**",'Pročitaj naša pravila u',"**[#✦pravila]**")
    .addField(':family_mwgb: | Sada si član', `${member.guild.memberCount}`)
    .addField("Name", `<@` + `${member.id}` + `>`, true)
    .addField(':family_mwgb: | Luda zabava tek počinje')
    .addField('Server', `${member.guild.name}`)
    .setFooter(`${member.guild.name}`)
    .setTimestamp()

channel.sendEmbed(embed);
```

});

Also make sure that you use the latest version of discord.js by using

```
npm i discord.js@latest
```

or

```
yarn add discord.js@latest
```

in your terminal. Then define `Discord` by writing

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

in the first line.